# Font family doesn't work on iPhone and footer freezes mid screen in iPhone

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, fonts

So i completed the website, but i seem to be getting a few errors. The font works fine on my computer, and the footer is positioned in the right place, but when I check the website on my iPhone, the footer is misplaced, and the font is different. I searched for fonts on google fonts and found one called OpenSans because I believe I read somewhere that those fonts are compatible with on a lot of mediums? Could someone please help? Thanks for your time to help, have a good day!

Here is a link to the screenshot to see what it looks like on the phone:http://imgur.com/Fgfjg54

the website is pinzoniradian.com if seeing the website would help to find solution if you need to inspect, or if you could see if you get any errors on your devices or systems. I am using a mac and my friend told me the images look slightly blurry on his computer compared to the pdf files i showed him.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Lindsey</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="css/yourCustom.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head> 
<body>
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand" style="color:#000000">Paulo Pinzon-Iradian</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collection of nav links and other content for toggling -->
        <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="work.html" style="color:#000000; margin-left:1.5em;">Work</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html" style="color:#000000; margin-left:1.5em;">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html" style="color:#000000; margin-left:1.5em;">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

      <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="item active">
            <img src="lindsey.jpg" style="width:370px;" alt="lindsey">
            <figcaption>Lindsey</figcaption>
            <figcaption>Damaged iPhone and Image</figcaption>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="liferockslifesucks.html" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="malek.html" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>

  <footer class="footer">
      <div class="container" style="display: table; height: 50px; overflow: hidden;">
        <p class="text-muted" style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">&copy; 2013-2015 Paulo Pinzon-Iradian, All Right Reserved</p>
      </div>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Css:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family:OpenSans-Regular;
    src:url(fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf);
}

.navbar-default{
    background: #fff;
    margin-top:2%;
    border:0px;
}

.navbar-brand
{
    font-family: Open Sans;
    font-size: 22px;
}

ul, li, a
{
    font-family: Open Sans;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: 100;
    letter-spacing:-1px;
}

.navbar-toggle
{
    border:0px;
}


.container .jumbotron.no-padding
{
    background: #fff;
    border:0px;
    font-family: Open Sans;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    color:#000000;
}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    text-align: right;
}
.footer .container {
    width: 100%;
}

.right.carousel-control, .left.carousel-control {
    opacity: 0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0); /* IE support */
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
}

img
{
    margin:auto;
}

figcaption
{
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: Have you trouble shot it in inspector yet?

Comment: No, the thought never came to mind, what would that do?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to include the Open-Sans google fonts code in the css at the start

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
```

After that every time you write Open-Sans do it like this so if Open-Sans wont load you have a bakup

```
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
```

Hope it helps

If you need a website go to [meadoweb.com](http://meadoweb.com)

Comment: Yes that worked! Thanks very much :) Sorry but is there a solution to the footer problem shown in the screenshot?

Comment: I dont understand? the footer seems fine in the center on the bottom.

Comment: if you need it in the center. Instead of the div try <center></center> tags.